# How to solve a basic Richter Scale problem using only If, elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I am a complete beginner but working through an exercise to write a program that reads input and displays the descriptor.

For the below code:

- Expected result is "Meteoric"
- Current result is "Very Minor"

I am aware this is basic but gotta start somewhere.

What am I doing wrong?

```
mag = float(10)

# Determine the richter 

if mag < float(2.0):
    print("Micro")
elif mag >= float(2.0) < float(3.0):
    print("Very Minor")
elif mag >= float(3.0) < float(4.0):
    print("Minor")
elif mag >= float(4.0) < float(5.0):
    print("Light")
elif mag >= float(5.0) < float(6.0):
    print("Moderate")
elif mag >= float(6.0) < float(7.0):
    print("Strong")
elif mag >= float(7.0) < float(8.0):
    print("Major")
elif mag >= float(8.0) < float(10.0):
    print("Great")
elif mag >= float(10.0):
    print("Meteoric")
else:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: Write the test like this: `mag >= 2.0 and mag < 3.0`, notice the conjunction with `and` and the repetition of the variable to compare against the static values.  You don't need to use `float()` if you write the constants with decimal point.

Comment: Why would anyone vote to close this excellent question as `not reproducible`? it is very much a copy-paste reproducible question, that can be learned from.

Comment: In addition to @TomRegner comment: You can also write `2. <= mag < 3.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got some of the conditions backwards.

What I did to solve it is make the code more readable (for myself) and then, like magic, the error went away.

I am saying, if you can read your code fast, it would probably mean you can debug it fast, which would imply it has fewer bugs.

1. Use only `<` and `<=`, and not `>` and `>=`, to always see *with your eyes* and not *with your logic* the conditions at hand
2. No need to convert numbers such as `3.0` to float.

**Working code:**

```
mag = float(10)

# Determine the richter

if mag < 2.0:
    print("Micro")
elif 2.0 <= mag < 3.0:
    print("Very Minor")
elif 3.0 <= mag < 4.0:
    print("Minor")
elif 4.0 <= mag < 5.0:
    print("Light")
elif 5.0 <= mag < 6.0:
    print("Moderate")
elif 6.0 <= mag < 7.0:
    print("Strong")
elif 7.0 <= mag < 8.0:
    print("Major")
elif 8.0 <= mag < 10.0:
    print("Great")
elif 10.0 <= mag:
    print("Meteoric")
else:
    print("Error")
```

The problem was:

Conditions such as
`mag >= float(2.0) < float(3.0):`

translate to

`mag >= float(2.0) and float(2.0) < float(3.0):`

which is the same as

`True and True:`

which is then

`True`

and you get `Very Minor`